# Looking for nginx rules to differentiate if a subfolder is listed or not

Tags: nginx

For example, if there is any subdirectory listed, keep the subdirectory. But if it's just the URL listed, then forward the user to localhost:3333/publiclink

```
  location /.(az)$ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  }

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333/publiclink;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  }
```

Comment: Is the URI `/foo` proxied to `/publiclink/foo` or just `/publiclink`?

Comment: If the user types in https://example.com or https://www.example.com and nothing else, they're redirected to example.com/publiclink. 
Anything with a subdir goes to that place: 
If the user types example.com/faq/ they go to example.com/faq/
If the user types example.com/pricing/ they go to example.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

You want the single URI `/` to be internally rewritten to `/publiclink` before passing it upstream, but everything else passes upstream transparently.

You can internally rewrite a single URI by using an exact match `location` with a `rewrite...last` statement:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /publiclink last;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
    ...
}
```

Or, use `rewrite...break` within the main `location`:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /publiclink break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
    ...
}
```

The first option is the more efficient.

Comment: This does point base URLs to /publiclink, but when I add a subdirectory like url.example.com/login

it's redirecting me back to /  (which is actually the /publiclink)

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2019:11:43:18 -0700] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://test.pgkyc.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2019:11:43:18 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2157 "https://test.pgkyc.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"